# Creating a simple Clock in QT

Tags: c++, qt, clock

I want to create a simple clock in my Qt program: QLabel which is updated once a second.

QLabel name: label_clock

My clock "script":

```
while (true)
{
   QString time1 = QTime::currentTime().toString();
   ui->label_clock->setText(time1);
}
```

But when I pase it into my program, you already know that it will stop executing it at this script - while will always give true, so rest of code under script will never execute -> program crashes.

What should I do to make this script work? I wanna create a simple clock which is being updated once a second.

Comment: Should'nt you at least "sleep" for one second between each iteration of the loop ?

Comment: @Max so what should I use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) for this. Try something like this:

```
QTimer *t = new QTimer(this);
t->setInterval(1000);
connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, [&]() {
   QString time1 = QTime::currentTime().toString();
   ui->label_clock->setText(time1);
} );
t->start();
```

Of course you should enable c++11 support (add to your `pro` file `CONFIG += c++11`).

Comment: Works fine, thank you. This is the thing, that I was searching for!